# Infinite animejs animation

Tags: javascript, animation, anime.js

I have a flowless pattern image and I am using background image with repeat.

With anime.js I am trying to do `backgroundPositionY: '-=10%'` every 5 seconds but I want it to run forever; and as the image is on repeat, it won't cause any visual problem.

Is it possible to do that with anime.js without creating a for loop or setInterval?

```
anime({
     targets: 'h1 > div',
     backgroundPositionY: '-=10%',
     easing: 'linear',
     duration: 5000,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the loop to true should play the animation infinitely. you may wish to additionally add `direction:'alternate'` too so it doesn't just reset after each loop

```
   anime({
     targets: 'h1 > div',
     backgroundPositionY: '-=10%',
     easing: 'linear',
     duration: 5000,
     loop:true
    });
```

Comment: `alternate` will just revert it though, won't it?

Comment: Yeah, alternate will shuffle it back and forth. Since you have a repeating background though, you can just set it to 100%, and as long as you don't alternate, it'll loop seamlessly. An anime animation always reverts to its starting point, but if your starting point and ending point look exactly the same, good loops happen.

Answer (score 1):

Anime.js animations reset to their initial position and follow the same path every time, even with only using offset coordinates. The trick around that is to never technically run the same animation twice.

By wrapping your animation in a function, and setting that function as the animation's `complete` callback, you can get an animation that doesn't repeat itself:

```js
function animate() {
  anime({
    targets: '#runaway',
    translateX: ["+=3em", "+=0", "+=0", "+=0"],
    translateY: ["+=0", "+=0", "+=3em", "+=0"],
    rotate: ["+=0", "+=90", "+=0", "-=90"],
    scaleX: ["*=-1", "+=0", "*=-1", "+=0"],
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'easeOutElastic(1, .8)',
    complete: animate,
  });
}

animate();
```

```css
#runaway {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: #698ac8;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<div id="runaway"></div>
```

Comment: How would I stop an animation like this in a component framework? Even when the target gets unmounted, it continues forever :/

Comment: I can't speak for your framework, but in the general case you stop an anime.js animation by calling its `.pause()` method. In a situation like this answer, you'd have to assign the animation to the global window object or something like that so you can keep a reference to it.